# Xamarin XAML Intellisense not working VS 2015

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, intellisense

I have tried to get intellisense working but no success.
Visual studio community edition 2015 update 2
Xamarin 4.0.4.4
Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.45
Enable XAML Language for Xamarin.Forms 1.1
No Resharper installed

I have tried suggestions on previous threads. No success.
Any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: Try to close solution and open it again. Also try to create a new project. My last recommendation to repair visual studio.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried all of the above, including repair of VS and de-installing xamarin and re-install. Still no success.

Comment: Does "previous threads" include https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/192579/#Comment_192579 by chance? "Close all open tabs in the project.  Quit Visual Studio.  Reopen the solution in Visual Studio.  Right-click the XAML file in the Solution Explorer and then select _Open With... > Source Code (Text) Editor_ as before.  Double-check that the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` appears all blue rather than red and blue."

Answer (score 0):

Try build project containing xaml file. The InteliSense should then work.

For writing Xaml you can also install any Extension: In menu Tools/Extensions and updates... click on-line node and type ***xaml xamarin*** to the Search input.